# Sql: Find if answer exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have two tables one with questions and one with answers. The questions schema consists of questionid,question,module id. One moduleid may have many questions.

```
Questionid   Question    Moduleid(FK)
--------     -----       -------
1            q1             1
2            q2             1
3            q4             2
4            q5             2
```

The answers schema consists of 3 columns

```
answerid     Answer    questionid(FK)
--------     -----       -------
1            a1             1
2            a2             2
3            a4             3
4            a5             4
```

I am trying to construct a stored procedure that I will send as parameter the @moduleid of tblquestions and I want it to return "1" if all the questions of the specific moduleid are answered in the tblquestions. (One question has ONLY one answer in tblanswers) Or return 0 if not all questions are answered. Any help on how to make this approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps there is something easier but this should work and enables to modify it easily to return all answered/not answered modules or missing answers of modules etc,.

```
SELECT CASE 
     WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM   tblquestions AS q 
                         INNER JOIN tblanswers AS a 
                                 ON q.questionid = a.questionid 
                  WHERE  ( q.moduleid = @ModuleId ) 
                         AND ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                           FROM   tblquestions AS q 
                                                  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                                                  tblanswers AS a 
                                                               ON 
                                                  q.questionid = 
                                                  a.questionid 
                                           WHERE  ( q.moduleid = @ModuleId ) 
                                                  AND ( a.answerid IS NULL ) 
                                          ) )) 
   THEN 1  ELSE 0 
   END  AS AllQuestionsAnswered
```

[**Here's the sql-fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6094c/8/2) with all module-ids, results are:

- ModuleID = 1 => 1
- ModuleID = 2 => 1
- ModuleID = 3 => 0

Comment: I would think you could put some of this logic into a UDF/TVF and, if necessary, `CROSS APPLY` it.

Comment: @CommanderOnets: But works and is less error-prone and easier to extend/change than the `COUNT` approach.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It works but how can I give a name to the column that returns the result?

Comment: @TimSchmelter `+1` using pure `ANSI` (except for the variable) as well as `Exists` :)

Answer (score 2):

Put this query inside the stored procedure.

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN (COUNT(a.QuestionID) = COUNT(b.QuestionID))
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
        END as AreAllAnswered
FROM    questions a
        LEFT JOIN answers b
            ON a.QuestionID = b.questionID
WHERE   a.ModuleID = @valueHere
```

The reason why you don't see a `GROUP BY` clause is because the records are already filtered by specific `ModuleID` only.

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*three queries included*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a419/3)

**FULL STORED PROCEDURE CODE**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcNameHere (@ModuleID INTEGER) 
AS 
    SELECT  CASE WHEN (COUNT(a.QuestionID) = COUNT(b.QuestionID))
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0
            END as AreAllAnswered
    FROM    questions a
            LEFT JOIN answers b
                ON a.QuestionID = b.questionID
    WHERE   a.ModuleID = @ModuleID
GO
```

**UPDATE 1**

if the OP allows multiple answers for every question, there is only a slight modification on the query,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcNameHere (@ModuleID INTEGER) 
AS 
    SELECT  CASE WHEN (COUNT(DISTINCT a.QuestionID) = COUNT(DISTINCT b.QuestionID))
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0
            END as AreAllAnswered
    FROM    questions a
            LEFT JOIN answers b
                ON a.QuestionID = b.questionID
    WHERE   a.ModuleID = @ModuleID
GO
```

Comment: May work now, but if OP wants to allow multiple answers(maybe invalids, versioned or deleted like here on SO) or multiple choice, then it won't work anymore. In my opionion `COUNT` is less maintanable and more error-prone  than `EXISTS`. Why should i count something when i want know if it exists?

Comment: @TimSchmelter even if OP allows multiple answers per question, there is only a slight modification on the statement. `COUNT(DISTINCT a.QuestionID) = COUNT(DISTINCT b.QuestionID)`

Comment: You haven't got my point. Archived/versioned/deleted answers should not count, multiple choice answers should not count since only one may be necessary. But all of this could also be constrained with a `WHERE` clause which is difficult with a `COUNT`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 I hope this may work....

 declare @que int
 declare @ans int
 set @que=( select count(*) from Question where moduleid=1)
 set @ans=(select count(Answer.questionid) from Answer inner join Question
 on Question.Questionid=Answer.questionid where Question.moduleid=1)
 if(@que = @ans)
 begin
   select 1
 end
 else
 begin
   select 0
 end
```